# Python error - cannot import my requirements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, miniconda

I'm trying to use several imports inside of a Python file.  However, none of them seem to be imported correctly.  I'm using a miniconda environment, and I've tried running Python versions 2.7 and 3.8 .

The following lines cause failures as soon as I run my app.  If I comment-out the first couple of lines, I just get the same error about openpyxl instead of dotenv.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
from openpyxl import Workbook
```

I have both of them listed in a requirements.txt file, and I'm able to run "pip install -r requirements.txt" without issues, but I still get errors when I try to run "python -m src.main".
The errors just look like this (below).  Any ideas on what else I can try?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/Users/path/a/b/src/main.py", line 2, in <module>
from dotenv import load_dotenv
ImportError: No module named dotenv
```

... or this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/Users/path/a/b/src/main.py", line 5, in <module>
from openpyxl import Workbook
ImportError: No module named openpyxl
```

EDIT:
Here's some additional information.  I'm thinking these paths got corrupted along the way.  Can someone tell me the expected output of these commands, inside of a miniconda environment?

```
(MyEnv2) MyMacbook:my-rep my-user$ which python
/usr/bin/python

(MyEnv2) MyMacbook:my-rep my-user$ which pip
/Users/my-user/opt/miniconda3/envs/MyEnv2/bin/pip

(MyEnv2) MyMacbook:my-rep my-user$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
```

Note - none of those paths match this one from my errors:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
```

Also, here is the output from echo $PATH:

```
/Users/my-user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.1/bin
:/usr/local/bin
:/usr/bin
:/bin
:/usr/sbin
:/sbin
:/Library/Python/2.7/bin
:/Library/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
:/usr/local/share/dotnet
:~/.dotnet/tools
:/Users/my-user/opt/miniconda3/envs/MyEnv2/bin
:/Users/my-user/opt/miniconda3/condabin
:/Users/my-user/google-cloud-sdk/bin
:/Users/my-user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.1/bin
:/Users/my-user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.1/bin
```

Comment: did you pip freeze to check if these modules are installed? If so, maybe try pip3 install -r requirements.txt

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed? Also, I see you are using Python 2.7, you should really migrate to 3 if you can.

Comment: "I've tried running Python versions 2.7 and 2.8"—There is no such thing as Python 2.8.

Comment: Make sure that you aren't running pip from a different location that your python by checking your `$path`

Comment: Show us the output of `pip show dotenv` (specifically the Location: line)

Comment: Sorry @khelwood - I meant 2.7 or 3.8 .  I've edited that.

Comment: @JohnGordon - The output is "WARNING: Package(s) not found: dotenv"

Comment: I don't understand how `pip install -r requirements.txt` can say that dotenv is already installed, but `pip show dotenv` says that it isn't.  Are you running both of those pip commands from the same environment?

Comment: Yes.  I think I need to reset a path or something to get it to stop blabbing about "2.7" because I'm now in an environment that's running 3.8 .

Comment: I added some more details at the bottom of the post, regarding the output when running which... from the terminal.

Comment: The issue is with your PATH. `which python` with the activated environment shouldn't return `/usr/bin/python` - which is the same as the one in `/System/Library`. Can you show `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I've added my echo $PATH output to the question body above.  Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so `which python` is correct because `/usr/bin` and `/Library/Python/2.7/bin` appears first. Then since system python doesn't have pip, `which pip` resolves to the virtualenv... Then somehow you've installed Python3 separately, which has put `pip3` also in `/usr/bin`... That being said, I don't think your venv activate script is updating the PATH correctly. Personally, I use `pyenv` and update my zshrc with that

Comment: @OneCricketeer - what SHOULD i see for those which commands?  should "which pip3"  also yield my MyEnv2 path, similar to "which pip" ?

Comment: So, with my `pyenv` setup, `pip3` and `pip` are the same, as they should be if you have activated a Python3 environment. That being said, where have you setup the PATH? You've got NVM in there three times, and ideally you make changes to the start rather than add to the end

Comment: Alright, I've got it sorted-out now.  Thanks everyone for the help!  Feel free to add an answer, and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by removing the following from: `/etc/paths`:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/bin
```

Once I had that line removed, I was able to see (nearly) identical output for `which pip`, `which pip3`, and `which python`.  All 3 output the following (with the appropriate app at the end of the path):

```
/Users/my-user/opt/miniconda3/envs/MyEnv2/bin/python
```